# Problem with the installation of Web ADF Runtime ArcGIS server 10

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, iis

I'm trying to install ArcGIS server 10 (Windows 7 32-bit) and I found problem in the installation of ArcGIS Server for the Microsoft .net Framework - Web ADF Runtime.

The error is:

```
    ArcGIS Server 10 - Web ADF Runtime cannot be installed on your machine. Web ADF Runtime requires Microsoft internet information services which has not been found on your system.
```

Comment: Are you using windows 7 home premium.....

Answer (score 2):

According to the message it means that IIS (Internet Information Services) is not installed .

Please install IIS after that reboot the machine then proceed for installation .

Step by step guide for win 7 32 bit : [How to install IIS on win 7 ?](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/365704/Install-IIS-on-Windows-7)

ArcGIS Server 10 : [Install guide](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#/Installing_ArcGIS_Server_for_the_Microsoft_NET_Framework_overview/00890000000t000000/)

thanks..

Comment: but i already installed the IIS with all the components listed and the problem persist!!

Comment: Did you reboot the machine ? What error message you are getting?Remove existing installation and Install again. Check out system requirement http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#//008900000007000000.htm

Comment: yes, i reboot the machine and also restart the service but the same error message

Answer (score 1):

the same error message which is 
        ArcGis Server 10 - web ADF run time cannot be installed on your machine. ArcGis Server 10 - Web ADF Run time requires Microsoft Internet Information Services, which has not been found on your system

Comment: i checked out on Mozilla Firefox and Google chrome but the result is page web inaccessible

Comment: It does work only with internet explorer

Comment: Good : ) that means it might permission/security issue.Do you have admin rights on your machine?If No then with the help of your IT admin account you can install the software..

Comment: actually, it was a question because i tried also with internet explorer and it's doesn't work also

Comment: should i have inetmgr install on my computer?